# How to fix an import from AD

Tags: windows, vb.net, active-directory

I'm not a developer, i'm trying to understand why my IT ticketing software is unable to import people from the windows AD. It was working ok a month ago. I have no access to the windows AD but they said "no changes or upgrades" recently made

I have isolated problem is related to the AD "manager" field, meaning, my ticketing software has an option not to try to import the manager field(or whatever it is) and it will work fine

Here is the code that performs the import

---

```
Option Explicit On ' Change to Off instead of On to disable the need to declare variables with Dim. (NOT recommended)
Option Strict Off ' Change to Off instead of On to cast variables automatically. (NOT recommended)
Option Compare Binary ' Change to Text instead of Binary to let string "A" equal to "a".

Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Collections
```

This is a transformation script class. Please take notice of the following rules:

```
' - You are not allowed to change the name of the class (must be "TransformationScript") 
' - You are not allowed to change the namespace the class is in (the class "TransformationScript" must not be in a namespace).
' - You are not allowed to change the name of the method (must be "Transform")
' - You are not allowed to change the parameters of the "Transform" method


' This method is called by the transformation logic. The dt parameter contains the data table with the data to transform.
' Any additional arguments are passed in the additionalArguments list.

Public Class TransformationScript
Public Sub Transform (ByVal dt As System.Data.DataTable, ByVal additionalArguments As SortedList)


For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
Dim strValue As String
If Not String.IsNullorEmpty(row.Item("manager").ToString)
strValue = row.Item("manager").ToString
Dim strArray() As String
Dim strManager As String
Dim strManagerDisplayName As String
```

split the AD manager object on "OU" and the results to array

```
strArray = strValue.Split("OU")
```

get string array position "0" that contains the manager name

```
strManager = strArray(0)
```

clean up the Manager display and remove the "CN=" and "\" and the last ","

```
strManagerDisplayName = strManager.Replace("CN=","") 
strManagerDisplayName = strManagerDisplayName.Replace("\","")
strManagerDisplayName = strManagerDisplayName.Remove(strManagerDisplayName.Length-1)
```

return the Manager Display Name

```
row.Item("manager") = strManagerDisplayName
End If
Next 

End Sub

End Class
```

---

I want to understand what the code is trying to do and possible root causes of what could be causing the issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is actually the issue? How is it not working? (Throwing an exception? Not the expected result?)

Comment: When trying to import from AD, if the manager to display is selected it won't ever try to run the import. If it's disabled it will run and import all AD people

Comment: The report doesn't run at all? Wouldn't that mean this code is never run?

Comment: I'm not sure of that but i guess it's possible

Comment: Set some breakpoints and step through the code.